# C++ Question - Using arrays to make a Login system

Tags: c++, arrays, authentication

I have a question. i have a login program written up that stores data using the while statement. If possible, is anyone able to take my code and make it work through an array, while keeping all the same features?
I am very new to C++ and was not successful at doing this.

Help would be very greatly appreciated! Code is provided below!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
  int loopCounter = 0;
  bool loggedIn = false
  while(loopCounter < 3){
    if((username == usernames[loopCounter]) && (password == passwords[loopCounter]){
      loggedIn = true;      
    }
  }
  if(!loggedIn){
    cout << "Loggin failed\n";
  }
 
  */
  int loginAttempts = 0;
  string username = "";
  string password = "";
  bool loginSuccess = false;
 
  cout << "\tWelcome. Please begin logging in! Input 'q' at any stage if you wish to quit the program.\n\n";
 
  do{
  cout << "Please input a username: ";
  cin >> username;
 
    while(username != "Bob" && username != "Tim" && username != "Mohammed" && username != "Sammy" && username != "Emma")  {
      loginAttempts++;
      if(loginAttempts > 3){
          cout << "Exceeded login attempts";
          return 0; // Exits program if the login attempts exceeds 3 at
    }
    if(username == "q"){
      return 0;
    }
 
    cout << "This username does not exist! Please reattempt to input a username!\n";
    cout << "Login Attempts: " << loginAttempts << endl;
    cout << "Please input a username: ";
      cin >> username;
  }
 
    cout << "\nUser found! Please enter the password!\n\n";
    cin >> password;
 
  if(password == "q"){
      return 0;
    }
  else if (username == "Bob" && password == "Password500") {
    cout << "\nSuccessful Login! Logged in as Bob!\n\n";
    cout << "\nWelcome Bob! You're a student. You are at standard access level!\n\n";
    loginSuccess = true;}
  else if (username == "Tim" && password == "Tim69") {
    cout << "\nSuccessful Login! Logged in as Tim!\n\n";
    cout << "\nWelcome Tim! You're a student. You are at standard access level!\n\n";
    loginSuccess = true;}
  else if (username == "Mohammed" && password == "Pineapples") {
    cout << "\nSuccessful Login! Logged in as Mohammed!\n\n";
    cout << "\nWelcome Mohammed! You're a student. You are at standard access level!\n\n";
    loginSuccess = true;}
  else if (username == "Sammy" && password == "GarlicBread") {
    cout << "\nSuccessful Login! Logged in as Sammy!\n\n";
    cout << "\nWelcome Sammy! You're a staff member! You are at privileged access level!\n\n";
    loginSuccess = true;}
  else if (username == "Emma" && password == "Sunflower03") {
    cout << "\nSuccessful Login! Logged in as Emma!\n\n";
    cout << "\nWelcome Emma, you're a staff member! You are at a privileged access level!\n\n";
    loginSuccess = true;}
  else{
    cout << "An incorrect password was provided! \n";
    cout << "Please try to relogin \n";
    loginAttempts++;
  }
    if (loginAttempts > 3){
      cout << "Exceeded login attempts";
  }
 
  }while(!loginSuccess && loginAttempts < 3);
  }
```

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment. In your program, what does loopcounter do?

Comment: Well the first thing you need to do is declare and populate your `usernames` and `passwords` arrays. Did you try that, what was the problem if you did? The next thing you need to do is move your code around so that you only check the user name and password after the user has entered them. Not sure if you've done functions yet, but I promise this whole task will be much easier if you can break it down into separate functions.

Comment: Unrelated (probably): `if((username == usernames[loopCounter]) && (password == passwords[loopCounter])` looks to be missing a `)`. Also a stray `*/` bunging things up. Missing `;` after `bool loggedIn = false`.

Comment: Also the first loop would be an infinite loop (ifnoring the fact that it doesn't compile). Btw: better declare a type containing both pieces of info for a single user instead of spreading the info accross multiple arrays.